# Do something before the Spinner opens the Dialog - Android

Tags: android, events, spinner

I´m trying to get the event that is called before the Dialog, with the radioButtons, is shown. But i couldn't. I tried to use the setOnTouchListener event, but it didn't work as I planned. So I imagined that there´s a event that controls de open and close function of the dialog of the spinner.

Does anyone know?!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at official documentation about dialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don´t know if I didn't express myself correctly, but I would like to control the Dialog of the Spinner. The one that shows all the itens